# $(element).css("height") returning undefined: something to do with the order in which my code is parsed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The basic layout of my code is

```
<html>
<head>
[...]
<style type="text/css">
[...]
        div#snakediv
        {
            width: 500px;
            height: 600px;
            border: 3px dashed #fff;
            margin: 0px;
            float: left;
            text-align: center;
            color: #39275b;
        }
[...]
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
      var SH = $("#snakediv").css("height");
      [...]
</script>
</head>
<body>
[...]
</body>
</html>
```

but for some reason `SH` is being set to `undefined` (I checked with the class `alert(...)` test). Right now I'm just manually setting `SH` equal to `600` so that the page runs correctly, but if you want to see the source code then look here: http://jaminweb.com/snake_TEST_PHP.php. I'm trying to figure out how to not have the number `600` floating around as a *magic number*. I have a feeling my current problem has something to do with the JavaScript getting parsed before the HTML elements have been created. Or something like that.

Comment: Your JavaScript code will be executed before the DOM has been built, so there won't be a "snakediv" in existence yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap your JavaScript in

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    /* JS here */
});
```

It then applies when the page is renderd. http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Am I allowed to define functions inside the $(document).ready(...) function?

Comment: @LilyCarter Yeah, sure. The ready function executes when the DOM is ready, that's all. Just wrap your code in this function and proceed as normal.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the DOM isn't ready yet wrap your code with `$(document).ready(function() {/* code goes here */});`

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

basically when an element isn't in the DOM it's height and width can't be checked as it doesn't have any.